# Rhythmbox control buttons not displayed properly

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, icons, rhythmbox

After an upgrade to Kubuntu 14.04 and to Rhythmbox 3.02 the control buttons in the upper left corner (play/stop, next/previous song, repeat, shuffle) and other icons (music library, libre.fm etc.) are not displayed properly.

Instead it shows an icon like a document with a question mark. They work, but don't look very nice. I tried reinstalling Rhythmbox, but that didn't help. What could be wrong?

[image: IMG]

I've tried the Gnome-Icon-Theme package and it tells me the newest version is already installed. The same for the Humanity-Icon-Theme.

Comment: it would be useful if you can post a link to a screen-shot.  At a guess, you probably need to install the gnome-icon set - `sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme` and/or possibly the `humanity-icon-theme` package.

Comment: @fossfreedom Thanks. Here's a link to a screenshot: dl.dropbox.com/u/2471034/Selection_001.png. Tried installing the Gnome-Icon-Theme and it tells me the newest version is already there. The same for the Humanity-Icon-Theme.

Comment: What above this package - is it installed? gnome-icon-theme-symbolic.  Possibly also this one - gnome-icon-theme-extras

Comment: @fossfreedom Great! The gnome-icon-theme-symbolic did the trick. Installed the gnome-icon-theme-extras as well, just in case. Thanks very much!

Comment: +1 for `gnome-icon-theme-symbolic`. Fixed it - haven't found the bug for weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Gnome icons

Rhythmbox has been for many years developed under the Gnome umbrella.

It inherits many of the requirements of other Gnome applications for the required packages.  This also includes the icons.

Since you've installed KDE/Kubuntu, this by default does not include the Gnome icon-sets - different code-base, different organisation.

Thus, to ensure a gnome-based application such as Rhythmbox looks and feels as the Gnome developers envisaged, you'll need to install their required packages.

To install the main icon-sets for Gnome-based application such as Rhythmbox will require you to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme, gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
```

If you intend to install more of the obscure Gnome based applications available, `gnome-icon-theme-extras` will also be required.